Geometric approach to minimize inner product
Problem :
Let $S$ be a surface
$$S : z = \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{2} + 1$$
For two point $Q(x,y,z)$ on $S$ and $P(2,0,1)$, evaluate
$$\min \frac{\mathrm{OP}\circ\mathrm{OQ}}{|\mathrm{OQ}|}$$

My Attempt :
Expand $\mathrm{OP}\circ\mathrm{OQ} = |\mathrm{OP}||\mathrm{OQ}|\cos\theta$ then we get
$$\frac{\mathrm{OP}\circ\mathrm{OQ}}{|\mathrm{OQ}|} = |\mathrm{OP}|\cos\theta$$
And we know this is related to projection $\mathrm{OP}$ to $\mathrm{OQ}$.
But this made me harder because in this problem, $\mathrm{OQ}$ varies, not $\mathrm{OP}$.
If $\mathrm{OQ}$ fixed, find normal line of $\overline{\mathrm{OQ}}$ which is tangent of $S$ and do projection to it then I can get minimum (or maximum) easily, But this case is different.
Is there any nice approach to avoid lagrange multiplier with three variables?

Are you sure $P$ is on $S$? I get $1=2$ when I plug it in.

Yup, as @infinitezero says, you need to check your question wording. The point $(2,0,1)$ is not on $z=\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{2}+1$, so either the coordinates of $P$ are wrong or the equation of the surface is (or both), or point $P$ isn't meant to be on $S$.

fwi: minimum is $-1/\sqrt{2}$ at $(-2,0,2)$

@infinitezero I mean that "two points $P$ (not on $S$) and $Q$ (on $S$). Let me edit the context, sorry for confusion anyway

What is $O$?${}{}$

I assume that $O$ is the origin $(0,0,0)$. Then we have to minimize $\cos\angle POQ\in [0,\pi]$, that is to maximize $\angle POQ$. Assume that $Q$ belongs to the plane $\pi_z$ consisting of points of $\mathbb R^3$ whose third coordinate equal some $z\ge 1$. Then $\angle POQ$ is maximized when $Q$ is the farthest point of the ellipse $$E_z=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3: \frac{x^2}4+\frac{y^2}2=z-1\right\}\subset \pi_z$$ from the intersection $P_z=(2z,0,z)$ of the ray $OP$ with the plane $\pi_z$. The squared distance
$$|QP_z|^2=(x-2z)^2+y^2=(x-2z)^2+2z-2-\frac{x^2}2=$$ $$\frac{x^2}2-4xz+4z^2+2z-2$$
is a quadratic function with the positive highest coefficient, so its maximum is attained when $x$ attains its minimal or maximal possible value, that is when $y=0$ and $x=-\sqrt{4z-4}$. Moreover, because of the summand $4xz$ we have to pick $x\le 0$. Thus we can restrict $Q$ to belong to the half of the parabola $z=\frac{x^2}4+1$ with $x\le 0$. Pick a point $R=(0,0,1)$ for the $Oz$ axis. Then $\angle POQ=\angle POR+\angle ROQ$. By the inequality between arithmetic and geometric means, $z\ge 2\sqrt{\frac{x^2}4\cdot 1}=-x$, so $\angle ROQ\le\frac {\pi}4$. Thus to maximize $\angle ROQ$ we have to maximize $\tan \angle ROQ=-\frac{x}{z}$, that is to minimize $f(x)=-\frac{x}4-\frac 1{x}$. By the inequality between arithmetic and geometric means, $f(x)\ge 2\sqrt{\frac{x}4\cdot \frac 1{x}}=1$, so the minimum of $f(x)$ is attained when $\frac{x}4=\frac 1{x}$, that is when $x=-2$. Then $z=2$, $|OQ|=2\sqrt{2}$, and $\frac{OP\circ OQ}{|OQ|}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Another approach:
Passing to spherical coordinates, the problem becomes the minimization of
$f(\rho,\theta,\phi)=2\cos\theta\sin\phi+\cos\phi$ subject to the constraint $g(\rho,\theta,\phi)=\rho\cos\phi-\frac14\rho^2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi-\frac12\rho^2\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi-1.$
The first equation of the system of Lagrange multipliers, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\rho}=\lambda\frac{\partial g}{\partial\rho}$, after multipilaction by $\rho$, gives
$$z=\frac12x^2+y^2.$$
This is what we needed to find.

Hosam said that "it is necessary that ... " But did give no proof
